# Retrieve from mysql if only contains two hyphen symbol

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like

```
+----------------------------+
| address                    |
+----------------------------+
| abc street edf road ---    |
| klm street number 10 --    |
+----------------------------+
```

When I use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%--%'
```

Retrieves both.

How can I only retrieve following data

```
+----------------------------+
| address                    |
+----------------------------+
| klm street number 10 --    |
+----------------------------+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%--%' AND address NOT LIKE '%---%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%--%' and address not like '%---%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%--%'  
        and length(address)-length(replace(address,'-',''))=2
```

Comment: Thank you for different solution! for now i prefer first option to keep it simple, but i am very happy that i learn another way to do this.

Comment: Second query will also return `'klm street number - 10 -'`.

Answer (score 2):

at this point, I can suggest this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%--%' and address NOT LIKE '%---%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE address REGEXP '-{2}' AND REGEXP '-{3}' = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for different solution!